# Math round and display in a div

Tags: javascript, html

I have a simple mortgage calculator and i want the final loan rate to be display rounded to two decimals.

Is it possible to achieve that? I'm ne to JS and i find out that i can use the `Math.round(value*100)/100` but i don't know exactly how to insert this funcion inside my js to display the correct rate inside the "#amount2"

Here's my code, hope that someone can help me. Thank you.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  function update() {
    $interesseannuo = 1.70;
    $C = $("#amount").val();
    $anni = $("#anni").val();
    $i = $interesseannuo / 12 / 100;
    $n = $anni * 12;
    $amount2 = $C * $i / (1 - Math.pow(1 + $i, -$n));


    $("#amount2").val($amount2);

  }

  debugger;

  $("#slider1").slider({
    max: 200000,
    min: 20000,
    step: 5000,
    slide: function(event, ui) {

      $("#amount").val(ui.value);
      update();

    }
  });





  $("#slider2").slider({
    max: 30,
    min: 10,
    step: 5,

    slide: function(event, ui) {

      $("#anni").val(ui.value);
      update();
    },
  });

  $("#anni").val($("#slider2").slider("value"));

  $("#anni").change(function(event) {
    var data = $("#anni").val();
    if (data.length > 0) {
      if (parseInt(data) >= 0 && parseInt(data) <= 31) {
        $("#slider2").slider("option", "value", data);
      } else {
        if (parseInt(data) < 1) {
          $("#anni").val("1");
          $("#slider2").slider("option", "value", "1");
        }
        if (parseInt(data) > 31) {
          $("#anni").val("31");
          $("#slider2").slider("option", "value", "31");
        }
      }
    } else {
      $("#slider2").slider("option", "value", "1");
    }
  });

  update();
});
```

```html
<link href="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.0/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.0/jquery-ui.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>



Totale mutuo (€)
<div id="slider1"></div>
<input type="text" id="amount" value="20000" /><br /><br /> Durata mutuo (anni)
<div id="slider2"></div>


<input type="text" id="anni" value="10" /><br /><br /> la Tua rata
<input id="amount2" type="text" /><br /><br />
```

Comment: `(1.23456).toFixed(2)` ;)

Comment: use num.toFixed(2) where num is your value you want to round off and then by using $(amount2).val = num.toFixed(2);

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Phew, there. I had to rewrite parts of your code, cache jQuery objects, etc. but now it works and it's cleaner.
Any reason why you use an old jQuery v1.12 (over 2 years old) ?

```js
const $amount = $("#amount"),
  $amount2 = $("#amount2"),
  $anni = $("#anni"),
  $slider1 = $("#slider1"),
  $slider2 = $("#slider2");

function update() {
  let interesseannuo = 1.70,
    C = $amount.val(),
    anni = $anni.val(),
    i = interesseannuo / 12 / 100,
    n = anni * 12,
    amount2 = C * i / (1 - Math.pow(1 + i, -n));

  $amount2.val(amount2.toFixed(2));
}

$slider1.slider({
  max: 200000,
  min: 20000,
  step: 5000,
  slide: function(event, ui) {
    $amount.val(ui.value);
    update();
  }
});

$slider2.slider({
  max: 30,
  min: 10,
  step: 5,
  slide: function(event, ui) {
    $anni.val(ui.value);
    update();
  },
});

$anni
  .val($slider2.slider("value"))
  .change(event => {
    var value = parseInt(event.target.value);
    if (value.length) {
      if (value >= 0 && value <= 31) {
        $slider2.slider("option", "value", data);
      } else {
        if (value < 1) {
          $anni.val("1");
          $slider2.slider("option", "value", "1");
        }
        if (value > 31) {
          $anni.val("31");
          $slider2.slider("option", "value", "31");
        }
      }
    } else {
      $slider2.slider("option", "value", "1");
    }
  });

update();
```

```html
<link href="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.0/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.0/jquery-ui.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>



Totale mutuo (€)
<div id="slider1"></div>
<input type="text" id="amount" value="20000" /><br /><br /> Durata mutuo (anni)
<div id="slider2"></div>


<input type="text" id="anni" value="10" /><br /><br /> la Tua rata
<input id="amount2" type="text" /><br /><br />
```

Comment: thank you, it works fine and the code is much cleaner!
no particular reasons to use this jquery, i've found part of the code online and it used that library.. you suggest to update it?

Comment: can you help me with another simple question?
as you can see i've changed the input tag "amount2" into a div but it's not working.. Plus i want that even the other input tag (#anni and #amount) to be simple div.. is this possible?

Comment: `you suggest to update it?` --> Well yes, obviously. Why would you use an outdated library? Use jQuery 3. `As you can see i've changed the input tag "amount2" into a div` --> Yeah, you did that by editing my answer, thus breaking it, so I rejected the change... `.val()` works for inputs because it acts on the `value` attribute. If you want to set the text inside a div, use `.text()` or `.html()`

Answer (score 0):

This might work:

```
Math.round(value*100)/100).toFixed(2);
```

Here is a link to a further discussion if this doesn't help: [Discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11832914/round-to-at-most-2-decimal-places-only-if-necessary)